# Excel How to find out how many times a piece has been rejected

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am a writer and have an exel spreadsheet detailing my submissions to publishing companies. I have two worksheets:

PIECES (all the short stories, novels and poetry listed
SUBMISSIONS RECORD (a detailed list of what was sent to where and the date it was rejected)

I have a rule not to send out one particular piece to more than five places at a time. However, I send out so often it's getting hard to figure out how many places a piece is still out to.

Whenever I receive a rejection/acceptance, I put the date of acceptance or rejection in a cell on SUBMISSIONS RECORD.

I would like to have a cell in PIECES that tells me how many submissions are out. It would do this by searching a column in SUBMISSIONS RECORD to find criteria and then checking an adjacent cell in SUBMISSIONS RECORD to see if it has a date in it. If its blank, that means its "still out" and I would like it to return a number so it would look like this:

SHORT STORY NAME      STILL OUT

My Story                5

Can anyone figure out how this can be done? SUMIF maybe?

Answer (score 0):

For the cell in PIECES, try using this formula structure that utilizes COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS([column in SUBMISSIONS RECORD],"[criteria]",[SUBMISSIONS RECORD date column],"="&"")
```

This will yield the number of instances that your "short story name" has a blank cell adjacent to it.

An example of this filled in looks like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(G:G,"My Story",H:H,"="&"")
```

Cheers.